# Nativescript building android errors

Tags: nativescript

I have a nativescript (3.0) application which I am developing on mac (ElCapitan).  I am able to run the iOS emulator without a problem, but I cannot find a way to build the app for Android.   I am getting the following error:

```html
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'MyApp'.
> Flavor 'nativescript-telerik-ui' has unknown dimension 'nativescript-telerik-ui'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.004 secs
Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1
```

I followed the nativescript documentation strictly, removed the android platform and added it again, reinstalled the Android SDK and tools, but without any success.

At this point I am out of ideas.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you should add tags to "android" or "gradle" since "Flavor" and "Dimensions" are Gradle terms

Comment: *This package has been deprecated* 
Did you check? what have been changed ... 
telerik-ui > nativescript-pro-ui > nativescript-ui

Answer (score 0):

did you try nuke it?

`tns plugin remove nativescript-telerik-ui
tns plugin add nativescript-telerik-ui`

my be you have an older version

Comment: yeah, I actually ended up scrapping the whole project and starting fresh and that fixed it.  Not sure what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have changed something on the "AndroidManifest.xml" file and which is not correct. Please fix the "AndroidManifest.xml" file.

If not, you can try this

```
tns platform remove android
tns platform add android
```

if only these two lines are not enough for the solution, you may run the android platform on Android Studio.

> app/platforms/android

This is the directory, you have to open on Android Studio. After opening this, Android Studio will suggest to you what you have to do.